# Actionscript 3.0 Timer doesn't display in text box

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, timer, actionscript

I am pretty new to actionscript and for one of my college finals I need to make a game.  I'm almost finished but one of the most important things I need is a simple timer to just count up by 1 from 0 continuously.  The timer works in my output but does not display in the textbox.  Here's a picture.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dFAE.png

Edit: The white box in the picture is just a white rectangle, the textbox is over top of it

**Code:**

```
var upCounter:int = 0
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000,0);

myTimer.addEventListener("timer", timerHandler)
myTimer.start();
myTimer:String;

function timerHandler(event:TimerEvent):void
{       
    trace(upCounter);       
    upCounter++;

}
```

Comment: You might need to embed the fonts. Also it would be useful if you show us the code you use for the text box.

Comment: Yes, please show how you are currently using the text field (in your photo there is no references to a text field).  Also, put code in your question, not in a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update your dynamic text field inside the `timerHandler` like this :

```
function timerHandler(event:TimerEvent):void
{       
    trace(upCounter);       
    upCounter++;

    text_field.text = (upCounter).toString();

}
```

Also, you have to remove this line : `myTimer:String;` because it is useless.

Comment: This actually doesn't work my swf starts flickering and I get this in my compiler errors:

access of possibly undefined property text through a reference with static type flash.utils:Timer

Comment: Try to add a text field and set it's type to dynamic and rename it, for example, text_field.